# Azure pre-triggers

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My goal is when I create a new item, the trigger sets the age to 18 years old.

this is my trigger function :

```
function trigger(item) {
    // Check if the document has an "age" field
    console.log("started triggering");
    if (item && item.age !== undefined) {
        // Update the "age" field to 18
        item.age = 18;
        console.log("done");
    }
    // Continue with the operation (insert)
    return item;
}
```

When I create new item, the age doesn't change
input :

```json
{
      "id": "86",
      "name": "dhia",
      "age": 11
}
```

output :

```json
{
    "id": "86",
    "name": "dhia",
    "age": 11
}
```

My goal is when I create a new item, the trigger sets the age to 18 years old.

I tried to set the name, the age, even a small change to see the trigger working because I'm learning and this is my first pre-trigger ever.

[image: Check image!]

Comment: Please edit to show all relevant code. For example, where are you calling the pre-trigger from? How are you replacing the item sent? As written, this looks like a UDF, not a pre-trigger.

Comment: Hello Mr David, 
Please note that I'm only setting the trigger on the Azure portal,
I want when I create new item I start my trigger to change the data.
I'm new so I don't know if it's the right way to do it.
I only go to the portal to my container and select the drop down list and choose trigger and then I choose 
Trigger Type pre
Trigger Operation create 
then I save and I insert new item with the portal and I expect the trigger to start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DhiaAkermi - I suggest looking at the docs for pre-trigger and UDF. What you wrote is essentially a UDF, even if you're calling it as a pre-trigger. You're doing nothing with `context`, etc.

Comment: I would avoid using Triggers. They are cumbersome to use and separate application logic that should be in the same place within your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is when I create a new item, the trigger sets the age to 18 years old.

As Gaurav Mantri explained in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969216/cosmos-db-trigger-is-not-being-run-when-inserting-new-document) thread, the triggers are not run automatically whenever a document is inserted. What you would need to do is specify the trigger that you want to run when you're creating the document.

**Below are the steps I followed:**

- An object is created by **CosmosClient** utilizing a connection string containing an Azure Cosmos DB account's login data.
- The `GetContainer` function is used to get a reference to a particular container within the Cosmos DB account.
- An anonymous type having the properties **id**, **name**, and **age** is used to define an object.
- It generates an `ItemRequestOptions` object and sets the `PreTriggers` property of that object to a list with the pre-trigger name **updateAge**. This pre-trigger will be executed before creating the item.
- `CreateItemAsync` method on the container is used to create the item asynchronously.
- The **item** is the new document, null shows that the code doesn't specify a particular partition key, and **requestOptions** has the pre-trigger data.

**Pre-Trigger:**

```js
function updateAge() {
  var context = getContext();
  var request = context.getRequest();
  var itemToCreate = request.getBody();
 
  itemToCreate.age = 18;

  request.setBody(itemToCreate);
}
```

- The request context and the object to be created are retrieved by `updateAge()`.
- It modifies the **age** property of the item to set it to **18**.
- Uses `request.setBody(itemToCreate)` to update the item's content with the modified **age** value.

**Below Is the code I tried with:**

```cs
public async Task CreateItemAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var client = new CosmosClient("*****");
        var container = client.GetContainer("newData", "newCont");

        var item = new
        {
            id = "3",
            name = "Pavan Balaji",
            age = 30
        };

        var requestOptions = new ItemRequestOptions
        {
            PreTriggers = new List<string> { "updateAge" }
        };

        var response = await container.CreateItemAsync(item, null, requestOptions);

        Console.WriteLine($"Request Charge: {response.RequestCharge}");
    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Cosmos DB Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassName Instance = new ClassName();
    await Instance.CreateItemAsync();
}
```

**Output:**

```js
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Pavan Balaji",
    "age": 18
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @Balaji this is very helpful!