# Cosmos Db pre or post triggers not being triggered

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos db for NoSql instance I'm working on.
I have a collection, let's coll it "my-coll".
I want to add a property in any document being added to the collection.

The [Training](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/expand-query-transaction-functionality-azure-cosmos-db-sql-api/4-add-triggers-operation) for the 'pre-trigger' has an example i want to reproduce.
The same is present in [Cosmos Db Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#pre-triggers).

```
function addLabel() {
  var context = getContext();
  var request = context.getRequest();
  var pendingItem = request.getBody();
  if (!('label' in pendingItem))
    pendingItem['label'] = 'new';
  request.setBody(pendingItem);
}
```

I created my new trigger from the Azure Portal CosmosDB explorer:

- Trigger Id: *createPreTrigger*
- Trigger Type: *Pre*
- Trigger Operation: *Create*

and then pasted the code.

I added a new Item from the Explorer. ***Nothing happened***.

I setup a postman collection and invoked the database api with a POST call and sending a payload.
The document is created. The label is not there, ***the trigger didn't work***.

## Why is that?

I'm exploring a real world production scenario, i need to save states in the document depending on creation or replacement, since the change feed with the operationType is not yet made public available.

All documentation available is in those 2 links above, sadly and embarrassingly. I need the triggers to work.

Please do not tell me that Azure Functions are a solution: as stated, they are not, due to the fact that change feed do not distinguish between insertion and replacement.

Thanks

Comment: it does! how did you find it?
i spent hours googling and binging, and even used the new SO AI search tool, trying to find a reference to this problem...
Thanks for link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as per [matias-quaranta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641598/matias-quaranta) comment, this is a duplicate of [cosmos-db-trigger-is-not-being-run-when-inserting-new-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969216/cosmos-db-trigger-is-not-being-run-when-inserting-new-document).

Currently CosmosDB does not work how a sane person would normally think, you need an SDK to trigger a pre or post trigger. Not Even the REST API can accept the trigger as a param. Just, the SDK.

Glad i didn't spend more than the last 3 days in trying to figure this thing out.

Thank you [matias-quaranta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641598/matias-quaranta)